# Shortcode not working in Jetpack Top Posts & Pages widget

Tags: shortcode, plugin-jetpack

I've added `[year]` shortcode to some of my posts' titles.

I used this in `functions.php` to enable this shortcode:

```
add_shortcode( 'year' , 'current_year' );
function current_year() {
    $year = date("Y");
    return "$year";
}
```

I then added this too to enable shortcodes in widgets:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

But the shortcode doesn't work in the post titles list shown by Top Posts & Pages widget by Jetpack.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Why have you added add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' ); ?

Comment: To enable shortcode usage in HTML widgets

Comment: You're going to need to debug your function current_year to make sure it is being called by the shortcode and then that it is returning something - if that's all good, then the issue is the add_filter call.

Comment: current_year is working fine. Is there any way to force do_shortcode in the Jetpack widget?